# Error loading csv file

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to load csv file into my table. I've run the following code which throws error

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'info.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_countryip (ipstart, ipend, countrycode) FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'  ;
```

The error is

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I even tried after removing the space between tablename and column names but still the same error
Thanks in advance

Comment: i dont understand `(ipstart, ipend, countrycode)`

Comment: these are all column names

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax-

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'info.csv'
INTO TABLE tbl_countryip
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5...);
```

Hope the below reference link help you

[MYSQL-LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: Actually I read that already they mentioned The column list can contain either column names or user variables.  That's why I have given the column names

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following changes:

1. Remove column names. Ensure columns and their sequence in csv file matches exactly with that of table.
2. Remove `\r` from LINES TERMINATED BY

Updated Query

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'info.csv'
INTO TABLE tbl_countryip
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

If first row in your csv file is a column name, use `IGNORE 1 LINES` after `LINES TERMINATED`.

Comment: the problem is the columns doesn't match